# Excel VBA Automate login to webpage with virtual keyboard

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm trying to login this webpage through VBA:

```
Sub scraping()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim LogonForm As HTMLFormElement
    Dim SubmitInput As HTMLInputElement

    UserName = "XXXXXXXXx"
    Password = "XXXXXXXXX"

    With Session
        Set IE = New InternetExplorer
        With IE
            .Navigate "https://www.unicajabanco.es/PortalServlet?pag=1110902071492&menu0=particulares"
            .Visible = True

            Do Until (.READYSTATE = 4 And Not .Busy)
                DoEvents
            Loop

            Set LogonForm = .document.datos

            With LogonForm

                .user.Value = UserName
                .clave.Focus
                .clave.Value = Password

                For Each SubmitInput In .getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
                    If InStr(SubmitInput.getAttribute("alt"), "de Banca") Then
                        SubmitInput.Click
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

But the input with `id="clave"` has a virtual keyboard attached in order to enter the password.

I've tried to fill the `clave` input using `.clave.Value = Password`, but when I click on `ENTRAR` button, the password is not recognized. It is if I had clicked the `ENTRAR` button without any value on `clave` input.

I've also tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
For Each SubmitInput In .getElementsByClassName("tecla")
    If InStr(SubmitInput.getAttribute("onclick"), "W") Then
        SubmitInput.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

And

```
For Each SubmitInput In .getElementsByTagName("div")
    If InStr(SubmitInput.getAttribute("onclick"), "W") Then
        SubmitInput.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

It will be appreciated if I could get some help entering the password and submitting the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bank web-site and it has extra security features to protect its users from hacking and the like.

If you inspect the page source, some of the html is created by having it written to the page via script rather than in the actual html - your `clave` input is an example.

`document.write('<input id="clave" class="campo" name="clave" maxlength="8" onBlur="blurVirtualKeyBoard(); if (this.value==\'\') datos.tipoTeclado.value=\'\';" onClick="if (this.value==\'\') datos.tipoTeclado.value=\'\';" onFocus="focusVirtualKeyBoard(this,\'acceso-usuario\',200,100);" readonly type="password"/>');`

Note that the `<input>` has a `readonly` attribute. Therefore trying to directly set the value of the `<input>` will fail unless you attempt to remove the attribute.

Some, or many, people will view attempting to remove this attribute as questionable behaviour given that web-scraping or automation can be legally dubious - especially with banking websites ;)

If you further inspect the page source you will see that clicking in the `<input>` starts a script called `acceso-usuario`. You might try following what that code does as a next step.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I will type de password through the virtualkey